# Clarification on sampling of sas data set using POINT option in set statement

Tags: sas

**Objective: sample 50 observations from whole data set (ALLOW / NOT ALLOW Repeat)**

1. I do not understanding what nObs usage for following script
2. How to sure whether repeat or not repeat is allowed?

   ```
   data carsample;
   do i = 1 to 50;
   slice = int(nObs*ranuni(123456));
   set sashelp.cars point=slice nobs = nObs; 
   end; 
   stop;
   run;
   ```

Comment: i don't know why i cannot make the code

Comment: a tip, You should use ceil instead of int, because for 500 observations int returns 0-499, ceil 1-500.

Comment: This is a pretty slow/poor way to do random sampling - both `proc surveyselect` and variations on k/n sampling are superior.  Also, `rand` is superior to `ranuni`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code that you have provided is the implementation of a random sampling method called "**Simple random sampling with replacement**(unrestricted random sampling)".

In this method, duplicates may come. To restrict the duplicates you have to remove them by writing another piece of code in the dataset "carsample".

We have one more sampling method which is effective and this will not allow duplicate records. It is "**Simple random sampling with out replacement**".

Now coming to your question,

1. Given a dataset sashelp.cars we have to select 50 sample observations. In the code we are using point= to select a particular observation.

For example: point=9 will select the 9th observation from the source dataset.

Let say we have 500 observations in sashelp.cars.

```
slice = int(nObs*ranuni(123456));
set sashelp.cars point=slice nobs = nObs;
```

Instead of nObs if you give 100, you will get random numbers(slice-variable) between 1 to 100, which in turn will fetch only records which are in between 1 and 100 in the source dataset.

if you give 1000, you will get random numbers(slice-variable) between 1 to 1000, which in turn will try to fetch records which are in between 1 and 1000 in the source dataset. However we only have 500 observations.

Hence we have to provide the exact number of observations in the source dataset and  **nobs=** is used.

2. As mentioned above, you can remove duplicates either by writing code to remove duplicates or by using "Simple random sampling with out replacement" method.

*Note: You can also make use of procedures like proc surveyselect*

Comment: hi @Kay i observed that the nObs variables in slice = statement is before the obs=nObs in set statement. How can the nObs be read in the slice = statement?

Comment: `nobs` is defined prior to the datastep running (since it's basically dataset metadata, and isn't something that depends on the specific data in the rows).  So it's available to use before it's actually declared.

Answer (score 1):

With `proc surveyselect` you have more explicit control over the sampling method used, e.g.

```
/*Default: simple random sampling (repeats not allowed)*/

proc surveyselect
  data = sashelp.cars
  out  = carsample
  n = 50
  ;
run;

/*Unrestricted random sampling (repeats allowed)*/

proc surveyselect
  data = sashelp.cars
  out  = carsample
  n = 50
  method = urs
  ;
run;
```